# Filter trigram tags with nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, collocation

I want to find out the trigrams of a corpus but with the restriction that at least two words of the trigrams are not proper nouns. This is my code so far.

```
def collocation_finder(text,window_size):

      ign = stopwords.words('english')


      #Clean the text
      finder = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(text, window_size) 
      finder.apply_freq_filter(2) 
      finder.apply_word_filter(lambda w: len(w) < 2 or w.lower() in ign)
      finder.apply_word_filter(lambda w: next(iter(w)) in propernouns)



      trig_mes = TrigramAssocMeasures()
      #Get trigrams based on raw frequency
      collocs = finder.nbest(trig_mes.raw_freq,10) 
      scores = finder.score_ngrams( trig_mes.raw_freq)

      return(collocs)
```

Where propernouns is a list of all the proper nouns in the corpus.

The thing is that my last word filter the one that was supposed to make sure that I don't go over my restriction. Any ideas?

Comment: Not understanding the last statement you made.

Comment: Sorry totally understandable that you got confused. I wanted to say that the last filter, the one with next(w) is wrong. I don't know how the apply_word_filter treats the text so I can't write the filtering fucntion. Essentialy I just want to know how to express my restriction ("at least two words of the trigrams are not proper nouns") as a function that is accepted by the apply_word_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be want you want

```
finder.apply_ngram_filter(lambda w1, w2, w3: sum([w1 n propernouns, w2 in propernouns, w3 in propernouns]) >= 2)
```